# Running logic off of promise result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, discord

I have a discord bot that wants to store discord UserIDs with city names in a database. The user will type the command !storeme [city name] and the bot will create a new document in the collection. For example, a user with id 123456789 types the command !storeme London:

```
{
    "userid": 123456789,
    "cityname": "London"
}
```

is then stored in the collection.

However, I only want each user to have one entry - and this cannot be changed. So when a user types a command, their userid is checked against the database to make sure it is not already associated with a city. This is where my issue arises.

```
function checkUserIdInDatabase(userID){
    const collection = db.collection("UserToCity")
    var result = collection.findOne({"userid": userID}, function(err, db){
        return !!result  // True if the user already exists in the database
    })
}

function storeme(user, cityname){
    // Do some data verification stuff here
    if (checkUserIdInDatabase(user.userID)){
       console.log("User already in the database!")
    } else {
       addUserToDatabase(user, cityname)  // This function is known to work
    }
}
```

My issue is that the conditional `if (checkUserIdInDatabase(user.userID))` always returns false, even if the user exists in the database. If I put the logic inside of the `collection.findOne()` anonymous function then it can easily determine this.

I then suppose that the issue is that in `storeme` the promise in `checkUserIdInDatabase` has not yet been resolved.

My question is how do I allow the function `storeme` to determine whether the user exists within the database? I could move the `collection.findOne()` into `storeme` and run all of the logic within the anonymous function, but that feels very clunky.

Answer (score 1):

Querying to database is an async task. So you should use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) Or [Async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) to handle the output.

In this case, You should rewrite your `checkUserIdInDatabase` with promise like this.

```
function checkUserIdInDatabase(userID) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const collection = db.collection("UserToCity")
    collection.findOne({ "userid": userID }, function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        db.close();
      }
      else {
        resolve(!!result);  // True if the user already exists in the database
        db.close();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

And call it in `storeme` function like.

```
function storeme(user, cityname) {
  // Do some data verification stuff here
  checkUserIdInDatabase(user.userID)
    .then(res => {
      if (res) {
        console.log("User already in the database!")
      }
      else {
        addUserToDatabase(user, cityname)  // This function is known to work
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // handle error
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was by wrapping the functionality in `storeme` into its own function, changing the code to look like this:

```
function checkUserIdInDatabase(userID){
    const collection = db.collection("UserToCity")
    var result = collection.findOne({"userid": userID}, function(err, db){
        return !!result  // True if the user already exists in the database
    })
}

function addUserToDatabase(user, cityname){
    const collection = db.collection("UserToCity")

    var result = collection.findOne({"userid": userID}, function(err, db){
        if (checkUserIdInDatabase(user.userID)){
           console.log("User already in the database!")
        } else {
           collection.add(user, cityname)
        }
    })

}

function storeme(user, cityname){
    // Do some data verification stuff here
    addUserToDatabase(user, cityname)
    // Any other stuff can be done here
}
```